# WPF binding to a ListBox.Items

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a simple window with a ListBox and a Label. I would like to bind the Label.Text to ListBox in such a manner to be the next Item of the listBox after the selected one shown in the Label.
I tried to use the multibinding with a converter like this:

```
 <Label>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="lbox" Path="Items"/>
            <Binding ElementName="lbox" Path="SelectedIndex"/>
      </MultiBinding>-->
 </Label>    

public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object[] items = values[0] as object[];
        int index = (int)(values[1]) + 1;
        return (items[index]).ToString();

    }
  .....
}
```

But it does not work. The problem is that I cannot get the array of ListBoxItems. Please could you help me?

Comment: Try using SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem in your MultiBinding. (Be aware that this code is extremely brittle even if it works.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok there are several things wrong here.

1. You aren't checking the index value before you try and get something out of the array. What happens if there is no selection, or what happens if they select the last row?
2. Calling the ToString() method of a listbox item will give you "System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem: Item's Text"
3. Lastly, and perhaps most directly answering your question, is the fact that the Items property is not an object[], but actually a ItemsCollection. Your code should look like this:

   ```
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
       System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection items = values[0] 
                           as System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection;

       int index = (int)(values[1]) + 1;

       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Is your code snippet correct? It looks to me that you want SelectedIndex and not SelectedValue (if I have understood your question correctly).
That is,

```
 <Label>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="lbox" Path="Items"/>
            <Binding ElementName="lbox" Path="SelectedIndex"/>
      </MultiBinding>
 </Label>
```

Note that at least you should have some error checking in your converter to check that your calculated index is still in range.

Comment: You´re right I mixed up SelectedItem and SelectedIndex. But it was just a mistake in the code and it does not solve the problem. The problem is that I cannot get an array of listboxItes. Object[] items has always null value.

Comment: I'd say you should take a look at the answer given by @ExitMusic which is pretty comprehensive in helping you out.